# Javascript encodeURIComponent() via GET is Not Found

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, get

I used encodeURIComponent() to form a link. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be routing properly. I think even though I've encoded it things aren't playing nicely when passed through GET.

Here's the URL that was generated:

```
http://www.example.com/add/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F/web%40web.com
```

Here's the .htaccess rule (it works if I put simple inputs in there):

```
RewriteRule ^add/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ add.php?link=$1&email=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Here's the result from browser:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /add/http://www.example.com//web@web.com was not found on this server.
```

What am I missing here? How do I fix it?

Comment: seems `%` and `.` would not match those regex's - try `RewriteRule ^add/([%.A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([%.A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ add.php?link=$1&email=$2 [PT,L,QSA]` ... checked with [this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: @JaromandaX So it' the rewrite rule? how can I fix it? I have regex blindness :)

Comment: use the one I put in the comment ... added `%.` to each regex ... you have `[A-Za-z0-9-]` ... I have `[%.A-Za-z0-9-]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to like it still

Comment: well, the .htaccess checker at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ suggests the resulting URL will be `http://www.example.com/add.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&email=web%40web.com`

Comment: For me it's still not finding the page though sadly :(

Comment: `/add.php` is correct? are you getting the same error? Have you tried restarting apache?

Comment: yep, everything is correct unfortunately. It works fine if I just put basic alphanumeric inputs in the url

Comment: maybe the `.` needs to be escaped ... `\.` ... that site doesn't guarantee anything :D